# Kubernetes master node not ready state

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I have fallowed the [this web site](https://darienmt.com/kubernetes/2019/03/31/kubernetes-at-home.html) to configure kubernetes in aws ubuntu(18.04) ec2 instance. I have fallowed same steps in above web page. But after applied Network Overlay, core dns pod's state not changed to running state.
[image]

My installed kubernetes version as bellow

- kubeadm - GitVersion:"v1.16.0"
- kubectl - GitVersion:"v1.16.0"
- kubelet - Kubernetes v1.16.0

resolve this issue i have tried the this answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086826/kubeadm-master-node-never-ready)

How can i resolve this issue ?

The output of `kubectl get nodes`

[image]

**out put of** `kubectl describe pod coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj -n kube-system`

```
  ubuntu@master:~$ sudo kubectl describe pod coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj -n kube-system
    Name:                 coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj
    Namespace:            kube-system
    Priority:             2000000000
    Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
    Node:                 <none>
    Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                          pod-template-hash=644d7b6d9
    Annotations:          <none>
    Status:               Pending
    IP:
    IPs:                  <none>
    Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/coredns-644d7b6d9
    Containers:
      coredns:
        Image:       k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.6.2
        Ports:       53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
        Host Ports:  0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
        Args:
          -conf
          /etc/coredns/Corefile
        Limits:
          memory:  170Mi
        Requests:
          cpu:        100m
          memory:     70Mi
        Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
        Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
        Environment:  <none>
        Mounts:
          /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
          /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from coredns-token-54rgm (ro)
    Conditions:
      Type           Status
      PodScheduled   False
    Volumes:
      config-volume:
        Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
        Name:      coredns
        Optional:  false
      coredns-token-54rgm:
        Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
        SecretName:  coredns-token-54rgm
        Optional:    false
    QoS Class:       Burstable
    Node-Selectors:  beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
    Tolerations:     CriticalAddonsOnly
                     node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                     node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
    Events:
      Type     Reason            Age        From               Message
      ----     ------            ----       ----               -------
      Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate                                   .
      Warning  FailedScheduling  <unknown>  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate
```

Comment: What is the output of `$ kubectl --namespace kube-system describe coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj`?

Comment: Also share the output of `kubectl get nodes` in the question description

Comment: @Junaid when i try to execute `kubectl --namespace kube-system describe coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj` command i get this message `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj"`

Comment: I might have written the coredns pod name wrong, please get any of the coredns pod name from kube-system namespace and run `kubectl --namespace kube-system describe <coredns-pod-name>`

Comment: @Junaid for the commond `kubectl get nodes` i have updated in the question

Comment: It should be `kubectl describe pod coredns-644d7b6d9-nv9mj -n kube-system`

Comment: I have update the question with the outputs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So basically there are some problems with flannel working on kubernetes v1.16 and you need to add `"cniVersion": "0.2.0"` to [kube-flannel.yml](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/d893bcbfe6b04791054aea6c7569dea4080cc289/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml#L108) file

```
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: psp.flannel.unprivileged
  annotations:
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: docker/default
    seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName: docker/default
    apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: runtime/default
    apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/defaultProfileName: runtime/default
spec:
  privileged: false
  volumes:
    - configMap
    - secret
    - emptyDir
    - hostPath
  allowedHostPaths:
    - pathPrefix: "/etc/cni/net.d"
    - pathPrefix: "/etc/kube-flannel"
    - pathPrefix: "/run/flannel"
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
  # Users and groups
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
  fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
  # Privilege Escalation
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  defaultAllowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  # Capabilities
  allowedCapabilities: ['NET_ADMIN']
  defaultAddCapabilities: []
  requiredDropCapabilities: []
  # Host namespaces
  hostPID: false
  hostIPC: false
  hostNetwork: true
  hostPorts:
  - min: 0
    max: 65535
  # SELinux
  seLinux:
    # SELinux is unsed in CaaSP
    rule: 'RunAsAny'
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: flannel
rules:
  - apiGroups: ['extensions']
    resources: ['podsecuritypolicies']
    verbs: ['use']
    resourceNames: ['psp.flannel.unprivileged']
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes/status
    verbs:
      - patch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: flannel
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: flannel
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: flannel
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: flannel
  namespace: kube-system
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-cfg
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
data:
  cni-conf.json: |
    {
      "name": "cbr0",
      "cniVersion": "0.2.0",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "type": "flannel",
          "delegate": {
            "hairpinMode": true,
            "isDefaultGateway": true
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "portmap",
          "capabilities": {
            "portMappings": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds-amd64
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flannel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      initContainers:
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64
        command:
        - cp
        args:
        - -f
        - /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json
        - /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-amd64
        command:
        - /opt/bin/flanneld
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
          capabilities:
             add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run/flannel
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run/flannel
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds-arm64
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flannel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: arm64
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      initContainers:
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-arm64
        command:
        - cp
        args:
        - -f
        - /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json
        - /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-arm64
        command:
        - /opt/bin/flanneld
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
          capabilities:
             add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run/flannel
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run/flannel
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds-arm
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flannel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: arm
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      initContainers:
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-arm
        command:
        - cp
        args:
        - -f
        - /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json
        - /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-arm
        command:
        - /opt/bin/flanneld
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
          capabilities:
             add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run/flannel
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run/flannel
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flannel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: ppc64le
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      initContainers:
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-ppc64le
        command:
        - cp
        args:
        - -f
        - /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json
        - /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-ppc64le
        command:
        - /opt/bin/flanneld
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
          capabilities:
             add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run/flannel
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run/flannel
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds-s390x
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flannel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/arch: s390x
      tolerations:
      - operator: Exists
        effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: flannel
      initContainers:
      - name: install-cni
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-s390x
        command:
        - cp
        args:
        - -f
        - /etc/kube-flannel/cni-conf.json
        - /etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cni
          mountPath: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      containers:
      - name: kube-flannel
        image: quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.11.0-s390x
        command:
        - /opt/bin/flanneld
        args:
        - --ip-masq
        - --kube-subnet-mgr
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
          limits:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "50Mi"
        securityContext:
          privileged: false
          capabilities:
             add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        volumeMounts:
        - name: run
          mountPath: /run/flannel
        - name: flannel-cfg
          mountPath: /etc/kube-flannel/
      volumes:
        - name: run
          hostPath:
            path: /run/flannel
        - name: cni
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        - name: flannel-cfg
          configMap:
            name: kube-flannel-cfg
```

I added this there so everything you need to do is use:

```
sudo kubeadm reset 

sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
```

use nano or vi to create a kube-flannel.yaml file and copy above yaml to it.

```
sudo kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yaml
```

Comment: @HarshanaSamaranayake that was my bad, yaml was wrong, edited, try now please,if i't wont work with your kubeadm init try with the one from kubernetes documentation `https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network`.

Let me know if it's work now.