# Kubernetes Master Not Ready after kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I have a fresh install of Kubernetes, running on an Amazon EC2.

kubectl get node reports that the node isn't ready after `kubeadm init`.

The first error in the logs is shown below.

```
journalctl -u kubelet
error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
```

Investigation of this error has not returned any results that indicate a fresh install.  Also these suggest the file is missing or has the wrong permissions or is empty.

The file as it appears in my EC2 is belongs to the same user and group as all it's peers.  It exists and is populated 876b.

```
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    cacheTTL: 0s
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
  webhook:
    cacheAuthorizedTTL: 0s
    cacheUnauthorizedTTL: 0s
cgroupDriver: systemd
clusterDNS:
- 10.96.0.10
clusterDomain: cluster.local
cpuManagerReconcilePeriod: 0s
evictionPressureTransitionPeriod: 0s
fileCheckFrequency: 0s
healthzBindAddress: 127.0.0.1
healthzPort: 10248
httpCheckFrequency: 0s
imageMinimumGCAge: 0s
kind: KubeletConfiguration
logging: {}
nodeStatusReportFrequency: 0s
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: 0s
rotateCertificates: true
runtimeRequestTimeout: 0s
shutdownGracePeriod: 0s
shutdownGracePeriodCriticalPods: 0s
staticPodPath: /etc/kubernetes/manifests
streamingConnectionIdleTimeout: 0s
syncFrequency: 0s
volumeStatsAggPeriod: 0s
```

I have tried applying the flannel from this question: [Kubernetes master node not ready state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024643/kubernetes-master-node-not-ready-state/58026895)

Additionally, I have tried applying Daemonsets from:  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-daemon/update-daemon-set/

Please let me know your thoughts, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issues remain as the master is not functional but the issue of Readiness is resolved.

These commands were applied from another question:  [kubeadm: master node never ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086826/kubeadm-master-node-never-ready)

```
 kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
 kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

Docker does show the containers still as being paused.